# Click GridView link And Send The Value To A TextBox?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, asplinkbutton

I'm a newbie in ASP.net development. I would like to ask on how to display data from grid view control to textbox control after click a link inside my gridview. Please note the code below for link. Also I don't want to use the auto generate select button since the display is default to "select" instead of the real data from my database.

```
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkView" runat="server" OnClick="lnkView_click" DataTextField="ID" SortExpression="ID"  CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID")%>'> 
                        </asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: what data you wanted to pass to the textbox control? is it a column data from the same row as the linkbutton?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ItemCommand event and then put CommandName in the like button. 
See the code below:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkView" runat="server" OnClick="lnkView_click" DataTextField="ID" SortExpression="ID" CommandName="something"  CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID")%>'> 
                    </asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

and in the gridview ItemCommand event then use the

```
protected void Gridview1_ItemCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.CommandName == "something")
    {
        Textboxid.text = "some text";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <ItemTemplate>
 <asp:LinkButton ID="HyperLinkIns" runat="server"
 OnClientClick='<%# GetUrl(Convert.ToString(Eval("id"))) %>'
 Text='<%# Shorten(Eval("id"),5,30) %>' ToolTip='<%# Eval("id") %>'>
  </asp:LinkButton>
  </ItemTemplate>
```

Cs:

```
protected string GetClientsHistoryUrl(string id)
{     
    return "javascript:window.open('http:// --- id=" + iinbin.ToString() + "','_blank','status= no, resizable= yes, scrollbars=yes, toolbar=no,location=no,menubar=no ')";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 protected void lbtAddNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        try {
            LinkButton lbt = (sender as LinkButton);
            GridViewRow gr=(lbt.NamingContainer as GridViewRow);
            txtbox1.text=gr.Cells[1].Text;
         }
        catch (Exception ex) { }
    }
```

in the above code, gr is having all the columns data for the particular row. so you can bind text to text box control